# Missing semicolon error msg at the start of function (react)

Tags: reactjs, semicolon-inference

Overview:
I just started learning react and I want to create a  where, after the "Submit" button is pressed I get an alert with the monthly income * 2 (Calc() function). However when I writhe the Calc() function I geht a parsing error and the msg that I am missing a semicolon. I am not sure why that is appearing since the missinge semicolon is in the same line where my ' Calc() {  ' code is and I never heard that at the start of a fucntiona semicolon is required.

Error msg:
[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io0e1.png)

Code below:

```
    export function Parttime(){

    const [monthly_income, setMonthly_income] = useState('');
```

//Error in same line where Calc() //

```
    Calc(){
        a = {monthly_income} * 2
        alert("Your monthly income times 2 is:", {a})
    }
```

//code continues after return( //

```
   return (
```

Screenshot of Error msg:

Comment: Check your function declaration. Your code will also fail at `a = {monthly_income}*2` since the variable isn't initialized. Looks like you are also using JSX in a javascript function with `monthly_income`

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function as arrow function

```
const Calc = () => {
// Your code
}
```